# Threads or DRb?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, threadpool, drb

I need to have 2 (or maybe 3) continuously running "facets" of a program in Ruby - a communications thread, a render thread and maybe a caching thread.

The idea is the rendering thread shows a slide-show (whose definition is read from file) and all slides are retrieved from a remote HTTP server by the communications thread. The rendering must be continuous and without stops (hence the probable need for caching). The file may change over the course of the program's lifetime and thus need re-parsing (on the fly).

I would like to send messages between the "facets" like when the comms thread gets a whole "chapter" of the show, the render thread could start before waiting for the whole show to be downloaded, for example, and so on.

Should I use Ruby threads or DRb? How can I pass messages between the threads?

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple to start with - always the best advice. Start with just two threads and see if the performance is what you need. You can use condition variable or simple Mutexes to synch around a list of retrieved chapters. You'll possibly get the problem of underrun - no chapter available for rendering but you'll at least have the bones of a workable solution using nothing more than core Ruby.

Then by all means look at solutions which offer other possibilities. Apart from DRb, you should also look at EventMachine (for the asynch capabilities you may need when reading chapters) and RabbitMQ for the more general and looser coupling that a messaging system offers.

Start small and don't try to move too fast. For anyone who has concerns about Ruby threads, I'm running a small report rendering client listening on a RabbitMQ queue. The client uses four threads for rendering the (google) graphs, sending alerts and automatically resetting various queues (after several hours of data have been gathered). All works great!

Chris

Comment: I'm only considering DRb because of the message passing capabilities - I can't have that with threads... right? I mean, I can hack it with mutexes but it's still a hack... right? :) DRb seems so much easier.

Comment: You only really need a message passing system if you need multiple processes. It doesn't sound like you need multiple processes hence I'd recommend keeping it simple. I'm doing something similar to yourself (gather remote data, process it and render an output) and a simple threading system will work great - I have a thread for each stage and one additional thread - no need for DRb. But use what you think you need!

Good luck!

Comment: IMHO, the RabbitMQ suggestion is the correct way to go.  I've done this kind of thing with both DRb and RabbitMQ before, and the DRb solution was less than ideal.  RabbitMQ is orders of magnitude faster, and if you're using celldee's Bunny library, it's also much easier.

Comment: Actually I'm using Bunny for part of our solution and it works great.